# certain keyboard keys become unresponsive. How to fix without reboot?

Tags: keyboard

Sometimes, some of my keyboard keys become unresponsive. (<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>arrows</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>shortcuts</kbd>... might be related to a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> key registering as constantly pressed?) I would normally suspect a hardware fault, particularly in a laptop as old as mine (7 years). But, after a reboot (or logout-login), the problem always goes away. That makes it seem like a software problem.

Is there any way to reset the keyboard without rebooting the whole computer (or at least the display manager)? Does anyone want to take a guess at what could be causing it?